# how to make combo box width variable according to longest option in extjs

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

In extjs, I want combo box width to increase according to the text in the option field but it should not affect the min width of the combo box. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Extjs ver 4.1 or above, you could use these [configs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-growToLongestValue)

```
grow: true,
growToLongestValue: true
```